# Ubuntu doesn't fit my laptop built-in screen

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, laptop, display-resolution, fujitsu-siemens

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a FS Esprimo V5555 notebook and I cannot see a very big part of the screen. (like I open system settings and the bottom half of it is out of the screen, I can't drag and drop and I can't scroll it) I only have 640x480 resolution in the settings (my notebook can do 1280x800, it has Sis Mirage 3). Same happened in 14.04 LTS. What could be a working solution?

(I am an absolute beginner about Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

If this has not been resolved in [18.04 LTS](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/) (and I suggest trying that first), another solution would be the use of Windows drivers through ndiswrapper, as documented at the official [Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper) for ndiswrapper.

`sudo apt-get install ndisgtk` allows you to install the GUI for ndiswrapper.

Comment: I couldn't find 32bit version of 18.04 LTS (originally I would installed that) but I tried Lubuntu 18.04, same problen occurs. But thanks, I'm gonna try Windows drivers

Comment: Especially recommend the 64 bit version for troubleshooting purposes. Your Core 2 Duo CPU should be able to handle it.